# Собственная функция вместо ButtonClick

Tags: c++, c++builder, события

C++ Builder 2006. Имеется БД Access, подключенная к Builder C++ через ADOConnection, ADOTable и DataSource. Необходимо вывести базу данных на форму не используя компонент dbgrid. То есть оформить вывод так как я хочу.

Логично, что нужно динамически генерировать элементы и в них записывать значения из полей таблицы.
Часть того как я делаю:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ADOTable1->RecordCount; i++) {
    Btn[i] = new TButton(UserMain);
    Btn[i]->Parent = UserMain;
    Btn[i]->Left = 240 + (220 * (i - 1)) * c;
    Btn[i]->Top = k * 270;
    Btn[i]->Name = "Button" + IntToStr(i);
    Btn[i]->Caption = "Подробнее";
}
```

В цикле так же генерируются и прочие элементы, но меня интересует именно Button
Количество этих кнопок меняется в зависимости от БД. Как на них навесить обработчик события клика, чтобы при этом выводилось разное сообщение в зависимости от кнопки?

Пробую сделать через обычную функцию, для проверки в качестве параметра передаю просто индекс:

```
void showAbout(int i) {
    ShowMessage(i);
}
//и в предыдущем цикле такое:
Btn[i]->OnClick = showAbout(i);
```

Но это выдает ошибку
**[C++ Error] Unit2.cpp(73): E2109 Not an allowed type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании пометьте во вспомогательном поле  - какой индекс имеет кнопка

```
Btn[i]->Tag = i;
```

Назначьте всем кнопкам один обработчик (обычную функцию нельзя - это должен быть метод объекта, соответствующий прототипу)

```
Btn[i]->OnClick = DynButtonClick;
```

А уже внутри обработчика смотрите Tag Sender-а и в зависимости от него что-то делайте

P.S. Вообще идея генерировать набор контролов на каждую запись БД - сомнительная. StringGrid-ом или TListView нельзя обойтись?

Comment: Решение мне частично подходит. Только вот индекс я привел в качестве примера(плохой пример), в идеале мне нужно чтобы каждая кнопка была привязана к определенному тексту. Или же можно передавать индекс, но потом как-то выбрать запись с ADOTable с этим индексом

Comment: Мне нужно оформить данные из БД в виде карточек как в Интернет-магазинах. Изображение товара - заголовок - кнопка "Подробнее", при клике по которой отображается описание товара на новой форме. Поэтому и не пользуюсь StringGrid-ом или ListView.

Comment: Если определенный текст - строка в памяти, то её адрес можно занести в Tag (с приведением типа). C выборкой же из таблицы - лучше отдельный вопрос сделать.

Comment: Табличные компоненты же и придуманы, чтобы не создавать миллион отдельных контролов. В общем-то, и в гриде и в ListView можно и картинки, и кнопки сделать (в гриде с кнопками немного сложнее - их можно просто рисовать)

Comment: А еще я получаю ошибку [C++ Error] Unit2.cpp(87): E2316 '_fastcall TUserMain::DynButtonClick(TObject *)' is not a member of 'TUserMain' и она в принципе логична

Comment: Нужно создать обработчик как метод формы. Самое простое - положить кнопку, сделать для неё обработчик нажатия непустой, потом кнопку удалить, а обработчик использовать